# If $\{a_n\} $ converges to $a$ and $\{b_n\}$ converges to $b$, and we have that $a_n < b_n$ for all $n$, is it true that $a<b$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta

> If $\{a_n\} $ converges to $a$ and $\{b_n\}$ converges to $b$, and we have that $a_n < b_n$ for all $n$, is it true that $a<b$?

I was thinking of some counterexample where the values sort of jump back and forth before they converge at some point, but eventually they need to "cluster" around two different points, and if they would not be ordered very far into the sequence, we would have a problem, so I think this is true. For a proof I would go back to the definition:

$ \forall \epsilon_0>0$ we know $\exists k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k\geq k_0$, we have that $|a_k -a|< \epsilon_0$, and similarly
$ \forall \epsilon_1>0$ we know $\exists k_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k\geq k_1$, we have that $|b_k -b|< \epsilon_1$.

For all $\epsilon>0$,

I suppose we want to pick a specific $\epsilon_0=\epsilon_1= \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
But now I am kind of stuck, I don't want to prove they are the same, I want to prove that the limits have a certain ordering.

Comment: No, limits don't preserve strict inequalities.

Comment: I am obviously not the one who downvoted.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Your question is fair (+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $a_n<b_n$ does not imply that $a<b$. take for example $a_n=-\frac{1}{n}\to a=0$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}\to b=0$.
Another example, $a_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}\to a=0$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{2n}\to b=0$

Comment: Of course! what if they go to the same point! Really clever, had not thought about that.

Comment: What do you mean? $-1/n$ and $1/n$ go to the same point $0$.

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying. My assumption was that the two points were distinct. I had not thought about equality of the limits.